# Why it's possible to declare a method that returns a type of the same class that's being created?

Tags: java, class, methods

I saw the next class:

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }
}
```

What i don't understand is why you can return a DetailsFragment type even though you´re just defining what a DetailsFragment is. For me (a novice), it's like searching a word in a dictionary and the definition uses the word itself to define it.

Please explain.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the constructor of a class is in the class itself, too. And that is what is actually used to construct an instance of a class. So why couldn't a static method of the class call this constructor? There's not much to explain. It's not only allowed, but is a common pattern named a factory method.

Comment: You need to distinguish between instances of classes and classes themselves. Classes are like definitions following your dictionary metaphor. Instantiating a class can be seen as using the definition (more of a template) to create the actual thing (e.g. an *apple* is an instance of class *Apple*).

Comment: You seem to have problems distinguishing declaring a class (and thus a type) from instantiating an object of that class (or type).

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: `String` has the `substring` methods, which allow a string to return a part of itself as a string; and `concat`, which returns a new string that is the concatenation of itself and another string. Hopefully you can see these are useful operations? Or, rather, how would you define such operations as instance methods if you couldn't refer to yourself in the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Constructor versus static factory method

The [`static` modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) on the `newInstance` method is the key. That modifier defines the method as standing apart, simply code to be run on its own, instead of defining behavior belonging to an object (an instance).

A static method is one of the parts of Java that is *not* [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Long story short, sometimes it is handy to just run a chunk of code without tying it to an object.

If you follow common Java naming conventions where a class is named with an initial upperclass character and an instance of that class is named with an initial lowercase letter, then you can easily spot the invocation of a static method.

```
DetailsFragment.newInstance()  // A static method call made on a class. Not object-oriented.
detailsFragment.someMethod()  // Instance method, invoked on one instance (one object) of type DetailsFragment named 'detailsFragment'.
```

So your `newInstance` method is *not* a constructor method. It is *like* a constructor method in that it aims to create an object. This kind of method is sometimes known as a factory method.

Your line of thinking is correct. A constructor that called `new` for the same class would cause an endless loop of object creating an object that creates an object and so on until the execution of your app failed. This repeating call to itself is known as [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). If uncontrolled, recursion is bad, causing your app to fail. Recursion on a factory method would also be bad in the same way, running endlessly until failure.

But here we have a factory method calling the constructor via call to `new`. So, no uncontrolled recursion, no recursion at all.

If you are new to these concepts, it can be tricky to wrap your mind around them. For me, the key is that when my eyes reach any use of the `static` modifier I think "not object-oriented" and shift my brain out of OOP mode and switch into thinking in terms of plain procedural code.

Visually, I think of a class as a cookie cutter, objects/instances are the cookies being produced, and a static method is a note tied by a string to the cookie cutter. That static method really has nothing to do with the class, but tying it to a class gives us a place to be kept, a way for us to find and invoke that method later.

Comment: That said, Dogs create dogs, and cats create cats, and it's perfectly allowed for instance methods of a class to create other instances of the same class, too.

Comment: It's not just about `static`, though. There are numerous examples of instance methods which return instances of the same class, e.g. `substring`, `concat`, `subList` (and `String.toString()`, but that's an unusual case!).

Comment: @AndyTurner & JBNizet I am addressing the specific issue of the question which I perceived as the author conflating a static factory method with a constructor. The two are indeed easily confused. We needn't explain every facet of OOP here, only the particular facet confusing the author.